# issue with wcf app config

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration, app-config

I have this code as a wcf service:

```
namespace ImeiTrackingService
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface IImeiTrackingSrv
{

    [OperationContract]
    DataTable GetSocsListFromCsv();

    [OperationContract]
    void Send_device_change_Notification(string sMdn, string sImei, string sImsi);
}
```

and this is what I have in my app.config:

```
<!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ImeiTrackingService.ImeiTrackingSrv">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ImeiTrackingService.IImeiTrackingSrv">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
   <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://imeitrk1.ram.eng.pel.internal/Send_device_change_Notification" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

when i try to run it on my web servers as: 
http://imeitrk1.ram.eng.pel.internal/Send_device_change_Notification

it doesn't work, but if I try it locally (with local host instead) it will work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Explain _doesn't work_.

Comment: i'm getting 404 from my rest client when i try to connect to the server while on localhost all works fine

Comment: Post full stack trace for the exception.

Comment: First, you have a SOAP service, not a REST service.  Second, it looks like you created a WCF Service **Library** - that means you need to copy the `<system.serivceModel>` section from the library's app.config to the app.config/web.config of the application using the DLL, as DLL's use the config file of the consuming application, not the one in the project template.